line: Get-PSDrive C | Select-Object @{Name="Free Disk Space percentage in GB"; Expression={($_.Free / 1GB * 100) / ($_.Used / 1GB + $_.Free / 1GB)}}
I'm trying to build a short script to execute on remote computers, but I'd like the output brief and to the point, I want it to read Free Disk Space percentage in GB I.E. 55.xx
I'm going to use the invoke-command cmdlet for the remote part. I thought I would use "{0:N2}" -f. I included it in the line but it did not do anything, the output remained 55.1234567890.
I'd appreciate any help, more to the point: what topic I should study to be better versed. I find that I learn better by solving an issue than by methodically studying the book from cover to cover. in this case, I want to learn how to control decimal points.
I tried using  "{0:N2}" -f and I expected it would format the output to 2 decimal points, I studied where I should insert the expression which was between the second braces, and start it with a parenthesis, and then closed parentheses before the second braces. but it did nothing, the output remained the same, no 'blood on the screen' either, it did nothing.

Please share more details, like the code involved
